# What is the Role of __FILE__ and __LINE__ + 1 When You Define has_rich_text Method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I found the following code in Rails, but couldn't figure out the role of `__FILE__` and `__LINE__ + 1`. Can anybody explain what for they are used when you define some method in `class_eval` like below?

```
def has_rich_text(name)
  class_eval <<-CODE, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
    def #{name}
      self.rich_text_#{name} ||= ActionText::RichText.new(name: "#{name}", record: self)
    end

    def #{name}=(body)
      self.#{name}.body = body
    end
  CODE

  has_one :"rich_text_#{name}", -> { where(name: name) }, class_name: "ActionText::RichText", as: :record, inverse_of: :record, dependent: :destroy

  scope :"with_rich_text_#{name}", -> { includes("rich_text_#{name}") }
  scope :"with_rich_text_#{name}_and_embeds", -> { includes("rich_text_#{name}": { embeds_attachments: :blob }) }

  after_save do
    public_send(name).save if public_send(name).changed?
  end
end
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what, *exactly* is unclear to you in the documentation of `Module#class_eval`. That way, the Ruby developers can improve the documentation so that future programmers don't come across the same problems you did.

Answer (score 5):

Error reporting (backtrace) is altered accordingly:

```
class Test
  def self.fun_ok(name)
    class_eval <<-CODE, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
      def #{name}; raise; end
    CODE
  end

  def self.fun_ko(name)
    class_eval <<-CODE
      def #{name}; raise; end
    CODE
  end
end
```

Let’s create the methods:

```
Test.fun_ok("ok")
Test.fun_ko("ko")
```

Let’s test:

```
begin
  Test.new.ok
rescue => e
  puts e.backtrace.inspect
end
#⇒ ["/tmp/foo.rb:4:in `ok'", "/tmp/foo.rb:19:in `<main>'"]

begin
  Test.new.ko
rescue => e
  puts e.backtrace.inspect
end
#⇒ ["(eval):1:in `ko'", "/tmp/foo.rb:25:in `<main>'"]
```

As you might see, the former backtrace is pointing to the exact line in the source code which led to the exception (particularily: `"/tmp/foo.rb:4"` part.) The latter one points to nowhere.